# View published EA html gives It appears that you may have Javascript disabled

Tags: enterprise-architect

I publish my Enterprise Architect v15.2.1560 package/diagram as a report.
when I open the index.htm from a network folder, I get: It appears that you may have Javascript disabled.
when I open the index.htm from a local folder, I get: Loading...

probably because my company restricts my windows installation.

I read on the Sparx website that I should open the report on a webserver.
How can I get the other two locations/alternatives to work?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have three options

- host the files on a webserver
- upgrade to v16 and generate the html from that version
- run Chrome with the flag `--allow-file-access-from-files`

This last option is unsafe and might open the door for malware. There is a reason Chrome doesn't allow that by default.

Comment: thanks for the quick and extensive answer. i will ask my company to upgrade.